# Firebase web init.js auto-configuration has selected the wrong API key

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a firebase site which initialises with
`<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>`
as described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls#sdk_auto-configuration

`init.js` is auto-generated by either the firebase deploy console or firebase hosting (I'm unclear which). This was all working fine until recently, when a new API key for my project was created in the https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials console. This new key had HTTP referrer restrictions, for some other domains (not my firebase site).
The next time I deployed my site after this key was created, firebase auth was broken. The error was `Requests from referer https://my-site.firebaseapp.com/ are blocked.`. I found the reason was because now `init.js` contained the wrong API key - the new, unrelated, restricted key, rather than the correct "Web API key" as shown in firebase console under settings -> General.

How do I control how init.js is generated? Is this a bug in firebase?

Comment: have you made sure to use the right project on your computer? You can see the project you are currently using by `firebase use` and change it by typing `firebase use <theproject>`

Comment: After contacting Firebase support they confirmed this is a bug. Workaround is to add the _correct_ contents of `init.js` into `index.html` instead, which will be very tricky if you deploy to more than one project/environment as I do :(
I'll post an update when they advise the issue fixed.